# Monitor spring boot with actuator over http

Tags: http, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When I use the default server address, I can get data from `localhost:8080/metrics`.

However when I set `server.address=172.20.7.24` in my *application.properties*, I can't get response from `172.20.7.24:8080/metrics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your properties:

```
management.address=172.20.7.24
```

[howto-change-the-http-port-or-address-of-the-actuator-endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port-or-address-of-the-actuator-endpoints):

> **78.1 Change the HTTP port or address of the actuator endpoints**
>
> In a standalone application the Actuator HTTP port defaults to the
>   same as the main HTTP port. To make the application listen on a
>   different port set the external property `management.port`. To listen on
>   a completely different network address (e.g. if you have an internal
>   network for management and an external one for user applications) you
>   can also set `management.address` to a valid IP address that the server
>   is able to bind to.

Comment: when I changed a computer,the problem disapear! And it's not nessesary to set the management.address=172.20.7.24,i can get the data from 172.20.7.24:8080/metrics.Thanks